# Почему внутренний блок подвисает внутри главного и не растягивается на всю высоту?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть главный блок `main` с картинкой и есть внутренний блок, который по идее должен растягиваться до низа своего основного блока, но он почему-то подвисает в воздухе. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/dzxc8k6e/) Наполнение в блоке `header-wrapper` может быть произвольным, заранее неизвестен, поэтому сразу предупреждаю вопросы - почему используется `min-height` в блоке `main`. Из-за чего происходит такое явление и как это дело поправить, естественно сохранив при этом кроссбраузерность `ie9+` и адаптивность на всех устройствах?

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 88px;
  padding-top: 86px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1920x312) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 312px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main .container {
  height: 100%;
}
#main .header-wrapper {
  min-height: 96px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(159, 105, 94, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) #main .header-wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
}
#main .header-wrapper {
  padding: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У блока #main нужно установить height: 1px .

### Кратко о проблеме

Когда у родительского элемента не установлен height, но указан min-height – необходимо установить height: 1px для родителя, чтобы дочерний элемент смог занять всю высоту указанную в min-height.

### Подробно

Можете почитать на [Xабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/189252/) (поиск по странице по «Роджер Йохансен»).

И пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUDnn/1/light/).

HTML

```html
<div class="parent fixed">
    <div class="child">My parent has <code>height: 1px</code>!</div>    
</div>


<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">My parent has only <code>min-height: 10em</code>!</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 1em;
}

.parent {
    width: 49%;
    float: right;
    min-height: 10em;
    background: deepskyblue;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.parent.fixed {
    float: left;
}

.fixed {
    height: 1px;
}

.child {
    padding: .25em;
    background: tomato;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**UPD 1**

В Вашем случае (содержимое блока .header-wrapper заранее не известно) можно указать минимальную высоту дочерних блоков исходя из минимальной высоты родительского. Если я правильно понял вопрос и какой Вам нужен результат.

```css
.container {
    min-height: 312px
}

.header-wrapper {
    padding: 80px;
    min-height: 152px;
}
```

Если указать для всех блоков box-sizing: border-box, то min-height: 312px для всех дочерних вне зависимости от padding и border.

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 88px;
  padding-top: 86px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/2000x2000) center/cover no-repeat;
  min-height: 312px;
  color: white;
}
#main .container {
  min-height: 312px;
}
#main .header-wrapper {
  padding: 80px;
  min-height: 152px;
  background-color: rgba(48, 148, 248, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD 2**

Если указать для всех блоков box-sizing: border-box, то:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 88px;
  padding-top: 86px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/2000x2000) center/cover no-repeat;
  min-height: 312px;
  color: white;
}
#main .container {
  min-height: inherit; /* или 312px */
}
#main .header-wrapper {
  padding: 80px;
  min-height: inherit; /* или 312px */
  background-color: rgba(48, 148, 248, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Либо указать минимальную высоту только у блока .header-wrapper:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 88px;
  padding-top: 86px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/2000x2000) center/cover no-repeat;
  color: white;
}
#main .container {
  
}
#main .header-wrapper {
  padding: 80px;
  min-height: 312px;
  background-color: rgba(48, 148, 248, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Что даст такой же результат.

Comment: да, в этом есть смысл и у меня так и было изначально, но смотрите, что происходит, когда содержимое контента превышает блок `main` - он вываливается из главного блока https://jsfiddle.net/dzxc8k6e/1/

Comment: @Вася, ответ обновлен с учетом Вашего комментария.

Comment: Отступ после .header-wrapper из-за display: inline-block. Посмотрите [документацию](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) по сеткам в Bootstrap. У родителя класс .row, который добавляет псевдоэлементы ::before и ::after (в Bootstrap используется [этот способ](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) очистки потока). У .header-wrapper удалите display: inline-block и добавьте класс .row (появятся отрицательные внешние отступы по горизонтали (margin-left/right: -15px), их можно переназначить конкретно для .header-wrapper).

Comment: отлично! супер, разобрался! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

1. Для #main задайте не min-height, а height. Ну и у .header-wrapper уберите min-height вообще - там же у Вас потом идёт height: 100%.
2. Задайте #main position: relative, а .header-wrapper position: absolute и width: 100%

Comment: нее, `height` не пойдет, потому что на меньших разрешениях контент будет вываливаться за границы `main`,поэтому нужно использование `min-height`

Comment: Ну, можно второй вариант использовать ))